# React default props are ignored

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm using **Flow v.0.52** typing in my *React* App, but I have a problem with correct assigning default props.

#### News.jsx

```js
class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    postList: {apiData: [], total: '0'},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPostListData(this.props.lang, null, this.props.category);
  }

  props: {
    postList: {apiData: Array<Content>, total: string},
    getPostListData: Function,
  };

  render() {
    const { postList } = this.props;
    let renderNewsCards;

    if (postList.apiData.length !== 0) {
      renderNewsCards = (
        <NewsCards ... />
      );
    } else {
      renderNewsCards = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loader...</p>;
    }
...
```

In **News.jsx** component default props ignored and in result `postList.apiData.length` encounter type error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

**P.S.** ***[Link](https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/6cb04d51d7c0561f9396e562640d3bbf)* to file  `News.jsx`**

Comment: try changing `static defaultProps = {` to `News.defaultProps = {`

Comment: @jsw324 no it's not working - ESLint is yelling  `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token`

Comment: According to the error, it sounds like `postList.apiData` is undefined, not `postList`. Seems like `postList` is getting passed as a prop from somewhere else (the redux connect?) and it doesn't have the `apiData` property

Comment: @john-shammas yes, `postList.apiData `  comes as a props from Redux store.  Because initial state in the reducer is `{}` hence  `postList.apiData ` is undefined and `postlist` itself is {}. But is it really matters where the props come from regarding default props?

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv if redux is passing in `{}`, then your default prop will never get used

Comment: @john-shammas ohhh now I get it. Of course  props  got to be `undefined`. Ok just write nice looking answer about it and bounty is yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the code you posted looks good.

From this error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

We can extrapolate that `postList.apiData` is undefined, while `postList` is indeed an Object. In what situation could this occur? Well, in the link you provided, `postList` is being bound to something in your redux store during your `connect()` procedure.

The error you received will occur when `yourReduxStore.postlistData` is an empty object. In that case, the default props will not be used, since `{}` is a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

I feel something is problem with the typings, I don't have much experience in flow script. But the below would work! Could your try and reply

```
import * as React from 'react'

type Content = number // assumed content type as number 
type Props = {
  postList: {apiData: Array<Content>, total: string},
  getPostListData: Function,
  lang: string,
  category: string
}

class News extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    postList: {apiData: [], total: '0'},
    lang: 'defaultLanguage',
    category: 'defaultCategory'
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return this.props.getPostListData(this.props.lang, null, this.props.category)
  } 

  render() {
    const { postList } = this.props;

    return postList.apiData.length !== 0 ?
      <div> news Cards </div> :
      <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loader...</p>
  }
}
```

Comment: why componentDidMount returns a function..., if you write outside component types then inside of it  `props: Props;` should be added, otherwise not working.

Answer (score 0):

the following solution worked for me,hope this solve your problem.

```
class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    postList: {apiData: [], total: '0'},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPostListData(this.props.lang, null, this.props.category);
  }

  props: {
    postList: {apiData: Array<Content>, total: string},
    getPostListData: Function,
  };

  render() {
    const { postList } = this.props;
    let renderNewsCards;

    if ((postList.apiData) && Object.keys(postList.apiData).length > 0){
      renderNewsCards = (
        <NewsCards ... />
      );
    } else {
      renderNewsCards = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loader...</p>;
    }
...
```